How can I make Nemo forget individual folder zoom levels?
Nemo remembers zoom settings for individual folders. I've recently changed the default zoom of the type of view I like, but now some folders I view show up too big and there could be a lot of them.
How can I make Nemo forget all the adjustments I've made over the years? I'd also like to disable the feature, if possible.
